# Angular NG6 IE assignment to read only properties is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, frontend

[View IE console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAuJP.png)

keep getting this error in IE and Mac safari and iOS devices.

in pageheader it only display **{{$ctrl.title}}** not the value, any idea about this?

Games.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import liveGamesViewComponent from './liveGamesView.component';

let liveGamesViewModule = angular.module('liveGamesView', [
    uiRouter
])
.component('liveGamesView', liveGamesViewComponent)
.config(($stateProvider) => {
    "ngInject";
    $stateProvider
        .state('livegames', {
            url: '/livegames',
            component: 'liveGamesView'
        });
})
.name;
export default liveGamesViewModule;
```

Games.html

```
<header>
    <page-header title="Games" bg-class="games"></page-header>
</header>
<main class="livegames">
</main>
```

PageHeader.component.js

```
import template from './pageHeader.html';
import controller from './pageHeader.controller';
import './pageHeader.less';
let pageHeaderComponent = {
    restrict: 'E',
    bindings: {
        title: '@',
        bgClass: '@'
    },
    template,
    controller
};
export default pageHeaderComponent;
```

Pageheader.html

```
<div class="page-header {{ $ctrl.bgClass }}">
    <div class="bg-mask"></div>
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1>{{ $ctrl.title }}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pageheader.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import pageHeaderComponent from './pageHeader.component';

let pageHeaderModule = angular.module('PageHeader', [
    uiRouter
])
.component('nblPageHeader', pageHeaderComponent)
.name;

export default pageHeaderModule;
```